# Google sheet api error: TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'json' - Python

Tags: python, json, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to use the google sheet api in my project. I am using the tutorial [in this link](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/02/an-easy-way-to-read-and-write-to-a-google-spreadsheet-in-python.html)

and I've got the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "spreadsheet.py", line 12, in <module>
sheet = client.open("Copy of Legislators 2017").sheet1
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gspread/client.py", line 82, in open
feed = self.get_spreadsheets_feed()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gspread/client.py", line 155, in get_spreadsheets_feed
r = self.session.get(url)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gspread/httpsession.py", line 73, in get
return self.request('GET', url, params=params, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gspread/httpsession.py", line 65, in request
response = func(url, data=data, params=params, headers=request_headers, files=files, json=json)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 467, in get
return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'json'
```

Here is the code that I am using:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials


# use creds to create a client to interact with the Google Drive API
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)
[enter link description here][1]client = gspread.authorize(creds)

# Find a workbook by name and open the first sheet
# Make sure you use the right name here.
sheet = client.open("Copy of Legislators 2017").sheet1

# Extract and print all of the values
list_of_hashes = sheet.get_all_records()
print(list_of_hashes)
```

I've search in the google for this error and I did not found a topic about this error yet.

The error appears when the command `sheet = client.open("Copy of Legislators 2017").sheet1` is executed

Answer (score 0):

I solved my error doing an upload of all necessary packages to python 3 and pip3.